# Upgrading to the latest Google AdMob SDK causes strange errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

I tried to upgrade to the latest Google AdMob SDK in my Xamarin.Forms app. So far I got the banner ads working but the interstitial ads throwing a error I'm not sure what it wants me todo. For the new callback parameter I added the following class:

```
private class LocalInterstitialAdLoadCallback : InterstitialAdLoadCallback
{
    public override void OnAdLoaded(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        if (p0 is InterstitialAd interstitialAd)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    interstitialAd.Show(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
                });
        }
    }

    public override void OnAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError p0)
    {
    }
}
```

but this yields the error below and I have no idea how to fix this.

```
javac.exe error JAVAC0000:  error: name clash: onAdLoaded(Object) in CoreService_LocalInterstitialAdLoadCallback and onAdLoaded(AdT) in AdLoadCallback have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
javac.exe error JAVAC0000:  public void onAdLoaded (java.lang.Object p0)
javac.exe error JAVAC0000:   where AdT is a type-variable:
javac.exe error JAVAC0000:     AdT extends Object declared in class AdLoadCallback
```

What does this even mean? Is there any sample on how to implement this properly or does someone have a hint where I can look this up? I never worked with Java which is not really helpful at this point I guess.

Comment: After the generic type is compiled, the type will be erased, leaving only the primitive type. For example, the T type in the parameter list will be compiled into Object, but there will be a Signature.
Although the two methods have the same bytecode, the type parameter information is recorded in the class schema with a new signature attribute. The JVM records this signature information when loading the class and makes it available through reflection at runtime.

Comment: This leads to this method can neither be used as a method to override the parent method, nor as an overload of the method.
So you can check whether the parent class has generics. If it has, make sure subclass has the generic type too.